# Quiz in Javascript with Arrays?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I'm trying to create a quiz in Javascript, by using number ids of the text inputs in HTML, then running a for loop and if to compare the input to the answer in an answers array.

In Html:

```
<form>
    China<input type="text" id="0"><br>
    France<input type="text" id="1"><br>
    Japan<input type="text" id="2"><br>
    <input type="button" id="submitt" value="submit">
</form>
```

In Javascript:

```
var answers = ["Beijing", "Paris", "Tokyo",];

$("#submitt").click(function() {
    var totalYes=0;
    function checkAnswers() {
        for(var i=0; i<answers.length; i++) {
            var userAnswer = document.getElementById(i);
            if(userAnswer.value===answers[i]) {
                totalYes++;
            }
        }
    }
    alert(totalYes);
    checkAnswers();
});
```

But the code doesn't add 1 to the variable `totalYes` (questions correct). I've tried `totalYes+=1` and `totalYes + 1` as well. The alert of totalYes shows up as 0 everytime.

But I know that's the only part not working because when I change totalYes to correct and incorrect alerts, it works:

```
var answers = ["Beijing", "Paris", "Tokyo",];

$("#submitt").click(function() {
    var totalYes=0;
    function checkAnswers() {
        for(var i=0; i<answers.length; i++) {
            var userAnswer = document.getElementById(i);
            if(userAnswer.value===answers[i]) {
                alert("Correct!");
            } else {
                alert("Incorrect!");
            }
        }
    }
    alert(totalYes);
    checkAnswers();
});
```

Please help?

Comment: Your javascript code does not look right. A function within a function?

Comment: @HeroFTime why not? It is a working code.

Comment: Because you are using a `for` loop for each question, any answer can be put into any textbox.  Example: Paris can be put in the textbox next to China and you'll still get 1 right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/6Lyxj/)

***NOTE:*** Because `totalYes` is a global variable you'll want to reset it to 0 after you show how many the user got right

**JS**

```
var answers = ["Beijing", "Paris", "Tokyo", ];
var totalYes = 0;

$("#submitt").click(function (e) {
    checkAnswers();
    alert(totalYes);
    e.preventDefault();
});

function checkAnswers() {
    for (var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
        var userAnswer = document.getElementById(i);
        if (userAnswer.value === answers[i]) {
            totalYes++;
        }
    }
}
```

---

***Side Note:*** This would be the easy test to cheat on...simply view source and you can see the JavaScript answers.  Perhaps you should `toLower()` the text and then `md5` or `sha1` the answers.  Then simply do the same when checking them

### [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/6Lyxj/1/)

```
var answers = ["feecd450f4886bbed257e222fcf7609cbdd57a64", "3c4bd4d0d0d1e076ce617723edd6a73afc9126ab", "0f1aae8b8398c20f81e1c36e349a7880c9234c63", ];
var totalYes = 0;

$("#submitt").click(function (e) {
    checkAnswers();
    alert(totalYes);
    e.preventDefault();
    totalYes = 0;
});

function checkAnswers() {
    for (var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
        var userAnswer = document.getElementById(i);
        if (Sha1.hash(userAnswer.value.toLowerCase()) === answers[i]) {
            totalYes++;
        }
    }
}
```

***Note:*** You will see some `sha1` code this code was taken from http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/sha1.html#code

*This will make it impossible without a rainbow table to simply view source to get the answer, I hope this is helpful in some small way*

---

***Extra note:*** Because you are using a `for` loop for each question, any answer can be put into any textbox.  Example: Paris can be put in the textbox next to China and you'll still get 1 right.

Answer (score 0):

The order of calling functions is not correct. You are first alerting your variable and then start counting correct answers. Change to:

```
$("#submitt").click(function() {
    var totalYes=0;
    function checkAnswers() {
        for(var i=0; i<answers.length; i++) {
            var userAnswer = document.getElementById(i);
            if(userAnswer.value===answers[i]) {
                totalYes++;
            }
        }
    }
    checkAnswers(); // check answers at the first place
    alert(totalYes);
});
```